# Why doesn't Gimp show in Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, gimp

Gimp doesn't show in the Unity Dash, despite having it installed, and having the appropriate desktop file (shown below) in `/usr/share/applications`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=GIMP Image Editor
GenericName=Image Editor
Comment=Create images and edit photographs
Exec=gimp-2.8 %U
TryExec=gimp-2.8
Icon=gimp
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;GTK;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=GIMP
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=General
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.8.2
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=gimp-2.8
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/postscript;application/pdf;image/bmp;image/g3fax;image/gif;image/x-fits;image/pcx;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-sgi;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-xcf;image/x-compressed-xcf;image/x-gimp-gbr;image/x-gimp-pat;image/x-gimp-gih;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psp;image/png;image/x-icon;image/x-xpixmap;image/svg+xml;application/pdf;image/x-wmf;image/jp2;image/jpeg2000;image/jpx;image/x-xcursor;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gimp20
```

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't show in the Unity launcher *even when it is running?*

Comment: Strangely, it did, but I can't search and run from dash, it just shows the "Free-Gimp", which links to Software Store, which says it's installed.

Comment: I recommend editing your question to explain this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file "/usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop" has proper **permissions**:

Right click in Nautilus > Properties > Permissions: **RW-R-R**

Comment: Yes, that is the permission setting.

Comment: It's odd... How about inserting a new line into its desktop file -- although it shouldn't be necessary: OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;

Answer (score 0):

After gimp was installed, my test system had these exact symptoms. After a reboot, gimp appears in my test system and the problem is fixed.